# Turnaround time for Optimized Autoscale to kick in after changing Cache Utilization

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Say my ADX cluster is set as Optimized Autoscale in the range [10,50] and the cluster is currently running at 30 nodes. Lets say cache utilization for my ADX cluster is 80% as of now. Considering these factors, if I now change cache policy for one of the tables and suddenly my cache utilization goes to 120% , how much time the Autoscale feature will take to start scale up operation on the cluster? And what is the cache utilization threshold for autoscale to kick in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will wait for an hour before adding more nodes (to ensure that it is not a transient issue) see more in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/manage-cluster-horizontal-scaling). Note that it takes additional few minutes for nodes to be added to the cluster.

The target cache utilization is 80%.